# Software architecture of Java SE in relation with JDK, JRE & JVM ? Beginner

Tags: jvm, java

My question is simple where can I add `Java SE` on this chart ? and what is `Utility Classes` on Java Terminology ? plz

[image]

Comment: A big box around everything.

Comment: Those 'utility classes' comprise the Java API.

Comment: @DaveNewton seriously ? What does it add more around `JDK` plz ?
@HannoBinder Only the API, you mean only Interfaces ? `Java SE` is not an API ? is it more ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If anything, I'd leave off the tools and re-label the JRE box as JSE 6, but IMO you're trying to make distinctions that are meaningless in real life.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am learning ... :)

Comment: "Java SE 6" is an indicator of the "profile" and version of a Java runtime or SDK. It's not an architectural element. That is, by contrast, a "Java EE 6" runtime is a SE runtime, a set of additional libraries, and an appserver to provide an application container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Java SE` encompass everything. It is the whole Java platform, but Standard Edition.

`Utility classes` is Java API.